# Running Azure CLI script from release pipeline using Service Principal - invalid_client

Tags: azure, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-cli

I have an Azure CLI script which runs perfectly well in the Cloud Shell but I run into trouble when I try to include it in a devops release pipeline. For debugging purposes I've reduced the script to simply signing-in as a *Service Principal* and then retrieving the version...

```
az login --service-principal -u http://[Service Principal name] -p [Service Principal password] --tenant [Service Principal tenant GUID]
az --version
```

...but it still incurs the same error.

Here are the properties of my *Azure CLI* task:

Script Type: `Shell`
Script Location: `Inline script`
Inline Script: [*as above*]
Script Arguments:
Access service principal details in script: `false`
Use global Azure CLI configuration: `false`
Working Directory:
Fail on Standard Error: `false`
Enabled: `true`
Continue on error: `false`*
Environment Variables:

And the error is:

> 2020-06-15T12:46:39.8710944Z ##[error]Error Code: [1]
>   2020-06-15T12:46:39.8724737Z ##[error]Error: Azure login failed
>   2020-06-15T12:46:39.8728448Z ##[error]Script failed with error: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired. Visit the Azure Portal to create new keys for your app, or consider using certificate credentials for added security: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials
>   Trace ID: d0f42793-739e-4ce9-9118-5049086aa800
>   Correlation ID: 2ad50471-9c2a-4c02-a4d0-189efad2f0c8
>   Timestamp: 2020-06-15 12:46:39Z","error_codes":[7000222],"timestamp":"2020-06-15 12:46:39Z","trace_id":"d0f42793-739e-4ce9-9118-5049086aa800","correlation_id":"2ad50471-9c2a-4c02-a4d0-189efad2f0c8","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000222"}

I was able to authenticate as this *Service Principal* using the Azure Cloud Shell so I'm puzzled as to why I apparently can't do the same from within the release pipeline.

* I have tried with *Continue on error: true* and although the task completes the same error appears in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the service principal in Azure CLI, no need to login manually.

For the correct way, please follow the steps below.

1.From the error message, the `client secret`(i.e. `client key`) of your service principal is expired. So you need to check it first, navigate to the [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) -> `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations` -> `All applications` -> find the AD App related to your service principal -> `Certificates & secrets` -> check if the secret is expired. If it is expired, just click `New client secret` to create a new one and save the value.

[image]

2.In devops, navigate to the `Project Settings` -> `Service connections` -> `New service connection` -> `Azure Resource Manager` -> `Service principal (manual)`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then fix the options with your service principal, you can get the values from your AD App in App registration page. The `Service Principal Id` is the `Application (client) ID`, the `Service principal key` is the `client secret`.

[image]

The `Subscription Id` and `Subscription Name` is which you want to use Azure CLI to access, you could find them in azure portal.

[image]

After input the values -> `Verify` -> `Verify and save`.

[image]

3.In your `Azure CLI` task -> `Azure Resource Manager connection` -> select the service connection in step 2. In my sample, I test to get a web app in my subscription with `az webapp show --name xxxx --resource-group xxxx`(**Note**: no need to use `az login` manually, it will login with the service principal which was configured in the service connection automatically).

[image]

Then run it and check the result, it works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very similar to the problem i faced earlier, it happens when there is a special character in the client secret.

One workaround is to go to the Azure portal and keep generating new secrets until you get one that does not have special characters in it.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/54914

Comment: What do you mean by "the client secret"? The auto-generated password?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret

Comment: It looks like the secret is an alternative to a certificate whereas I'm trying to authenticate using a password, which is the alternative to a cert. I thought it was a cert/secret or a password - am I wrong?

Comment: you mean this ? https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/905

Comment: Jeez.. yet another undocumented Azure 'feature'.